# Parsing a SOAP response in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I'm trying to parse a `SOAP` response from a server.  I'm 100% new to `SOAP` and pretty new to communicating using `HTTP`/`HTTPS`.  I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

It looks like `SOAP` is very much like `XML`.  However, I seem to be unable to parse it as such.  I've tried to use `ElementTree` but keep getting errors.  From searches I've been able to conclude that there may be issues with the `SOAP` tags.  (I could be way off here...let me know if I am.)

So, here is an example of the `SOAP` message I have and what I'm trying to do to parse it (this is an actual server response from Link Point Gateway, in case that's relevant).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
soap_string = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse xmlns:fdggwsapi="http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi"><fdggwsapi:CommercialServiceProvider/><fdggwsapi:TransactionTime>Wed Jul 25 10:26:40 2012</fdggwsapi:TransactionTime><fdggwsapi:TransactionID/><fdggwsapi:ProcessorReferenceNumber/><fdggwsapi:ProcessorResponseMessage/><fdggwsapi:ErrorMessage>SGS-002303: Invalid credit card number.</fdggwsapi:ErrorMessage><fdggwsapi:OrderId>1</fdggwsapi:OrderId><fdggwsapi:ApprovalCode/><fdggwsapi:AVSResponse/><fdggwsapi:TDate/><fdggwsapi:TransactionResult>FAILED</fdggwsapi:TransactionResult><fdggwsapi:ProcessorResponseCode/><fdggwsapi:ProcessorApprovalCode/><fdggwsapi:CalculatedTax/><fdggwsapi:CalculatedShipping/><fdggwsapi:TransactionScore/><fdggwsapi:FraudAction/><fdggwsapi:AuthenticationResponseCode/></fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
targetTree = ET.fromstring(soap_string)
```

This yields the following error:

```
unbound prefix: line 1, column 0
```

From another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434288/issue-parsing-a-xhtml-page-using-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) I've concluded that `SOAP-ENV:Body` may be causing a namespace problem. (I could be wrong.)

I've done other searches to find a good solution for parsing `SOAP` but most of them are from 3+ years ago.  It seems that [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) is pretty highly recommended.  I wanted to get "updated" recommendations before I got too far down a path.

Can anyone recommend a solid (and easy) way to parse a `SOAP` response like the one I received above?  It would be appreciated if you could provide a simple example to get me started (as I said above, I'm completely new to `SOAP`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a straight-forward approach using Python.  I decided to use PHP instead.

Much like the following:

Python:

```
import subprocess
command = 'php /path/to/script.php "{1}"'.format(soap_string)
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
output = process.communicate()[0]
(error, result, order_id) = output.split(',')
```

PHP:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$soap_response = $argv[1];

$doc = simplexml_load_string($soap_response);
$doc->registerXPathNamespace('fdggwsapi', 'http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi');
$nodes = $doc->xpath('//fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse/fdggwsapi:ErrorMessage');
$error = strval($nodes[0]);

$nodes = $doc->xpath('//fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse/fdggwsapi:TransactionResult');
$result = strval($nodes[0]);

$nodes = $doc->xpath('//fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse/fdggwsapi:OrderId');
$order_id = strval($nodes[0]);

$array = array($error, $result, $order_id);
$response = implode(',', $array);

echo $response;
```

This code only parses specific aspects of this particular `SOAP` response.  It should be enough to get you going to solve your problem.

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to PHP (I've used Perl a bit so that helped).  I must give credit to [@scoffey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311254/scoffey) for [his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048685/php-parse-data-from-a-soap-response?answertab=votes#tab-top) to parsing `SOAP` in a way that **finally** made sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: 
Working with SOAP in Python is really fun - most tools are not maintained for years. If we talk about features - maybe [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html) is the leader. But it has lots of bugs if it comes to support some more complex XSD schemas(just one example - it doesn't support unions and complex types based on extensions, where the extended type is not a base type).
[Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) is very easy to use, but not so powerful as ZSI - it has worse support for some complex XSD constructs than ZSI.
There is an interesting tool - [generateDS](http://cutter.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html), which works with XSD and not directly with WSDL - you have to implement the methods yourself. But it does a pretty good job actually.

Comment: Sorry, I did notice that earlier and forgot to update the question.

Comment: The edited question and the example works for me. I don't get this error... Is there anything missing ?

Comment: I don't think so...I must have just missed the first envelope.  =-/

Comment: Okay, never mind. I've updated the answer. It seems you've solved your problem. And maybe for good. With Python there are more problems with SOAP than solutions :) Just keep to what works for you :)